# How to pass the run-time parameter using the <forward> in the struts-config.xml?

Tags: redirect, struts, forward-declaration, forward, struts-1

I want to pass the string using the paramter of 'multitablesid' with different name. Because I am using the export to excel using our jar file. Here am using the struts1.2.9. In my scenario I want to pass the url in the struts-config.xml using the `<forward path="">`.

Here is my code,

```
<forward name="WeeklyDeliveryInstancesExcelReport" path="/MultiTableExportServlet?multitablesId=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count&amp;name=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count&amp;type=excel" ></forward>
```

I want to pass the multitablesid='differntname'. But I need each and every request came from the JSP page and finally forwarded to different name. The loop works for 13 times. What can I do?